# ionic2 update menu works in browser, not in ionic view

Tags: menu, ionic2

I have my App working in the browser (ionic serve):

- singleton provider sets `showLogin` to `false`
- upon login this value is updated
- menu shows/hides items based on `showLogin` value

but when I upload it and test on IOS or Android the menu is not updated upon login (only when I close the App and reopen it). I am not sure why.

App.html:

```html
<ion-menu [content]="mainContent">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>
        Menu
      </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content id="side-menu21">
    <ion-list id="menu-list1">
      <ion-item color="none" menuClose="" on-click="goToDriveBidder()" id="menu-list-item1">
        Home
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item color="none" menuClose="" on-click="goToHuidigeRit()" id="menu-list-item2" [hidden]="!singleton.showLogin">
        Huidige rit
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item color="none" menuClose="" on-click="goToMijnRitten()" id="menu-list-item3" [hidden]="!singleton.showLogin">
        Mijn ritten
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item color="none" menuClose="" on-click="goToLogout()" id="menu-list-item3" [hidden]="!singleton.showLogin">
        Logout
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item color="none" menuClose="" on-click="goToLogin()" id="menu-list-item3" [hidden]="singleton.showLogin">
        Login
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item color="none" menuClose="" on-click="goToHelp()" id="menu-list-item4">
        Help
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav #mainContent [root]="rootPage" swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

singleton.ts:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SingletonService {
    public showLogin:boolean = false;
}
```

and login.ts updates `showLogin` when login is succesful:

```
this.singleton.showLogin = true;
```

and it redirects to the homepage:

```
location.reload(true);
```

In the browser the correct menu items show now, but not in ionic view....what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try attaching your phone using USB and debug it with Google Chrome to see if there're any errors?

Comment: no errors...it just doesn't do anything